# Can I select an element by data-testid using #?

Tags: typescript, element, playwright

Just like the id can be selected using

```js
await page.locator("#YourId").click()
```

is there a shorthand for `data-testid` in playwright-typescript ?

I tried

```js
await page.locator("#YourData-testid").click()
```

I was expecting the element with the `data-testid` to be clicked but it is not located for click action.

Answer (score 10):

The `#` shorthand symbol for id is actually specific to/provided by CSS selectors, which is what’s being used by `.locator()`. Since data-testid is nothing special to css selectors, since it’s not meant for styling, the only way with css selectors is with the attribute notation:

```js
.locator('[data-testid="value"]')
```

That being said, Playwright does provide [the `.getByTestId()` convenience method](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#locate-by-test-id) for selecting by that attribute:

```js
.getByTestId('value')
```

Comment: Note that there's [`selectors.setTestIdAttribute`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-selectors#selectors-set-test-id-attribute) to override `data-testid`. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77849633/6243352).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [CSS attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp).  In this case, you'd want something like

`page.locator('[data-testid="YourData"]')`

More examples [here](https://thats-it-code.com/playwright/playwright__find-locate-search-elements-tags/#playwright-find-elementstags-by-attribute)