# Playwright Error: Error: locator.fill: Unknown engine "data-qa" while parsing selector data-qa=login-input-email

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

I am new to Playwright. I am getting an error below:

```
Error: locator.fill: Unknown engine "data-qa" while parsing selector data-qa=login-input-email
```

This is my Page file where my locator and method is written:

```js
export class LoginPage {
    /**
     * @param {import('@playwright/test').Page} page
     */
    constructor(page) {
      this.page = page;
      this.userName = this.page.locator('data-qa=login-input-email');
      this.password = this.page.locator('data-qa=login-input-password');
      this.loginButton = this.page.locator('data-qa=login-button');
    }
  
    async goto() {
      await this.page.goto('https://www.baseurl.com/login');
    }
  
    /**
     * @param {string} text
     */
    async enterUsername(text) {
      await this.userName.fill(text);
    }

    /**
     * @param {string} text
     */
    async enterPassword(text) {
        await this.password.fill(text);
      }

    async clickLoginBtn() {
        await this.loginButton.click();
    }
  }
```

This is my spec file:

```js
// @ts-check
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

import { LoginPage } from '../../pages/login-page'

// const { LoginPage } = require('../../pages/login-page');

const username = 'user@email.com';
const password = 'test123_mcx6bca8CHK.tup';


test.describe('Login', () => {
  
  test('Validates the login', async ({ page }) => {
    
    const loginPage = new LoginPage(page);

    loginPage.goto();
    loginPage.enterUsername(username);
    loginPage.enterPassword(password);
    loginPage.clickLoginBtn();
  })
})
```

Here's the locator. Please note that we are required to use `data-qa`.

[screenshot of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKBWZ.png)

Comment: `loginPage.goto();` and all the other `loginPage` methods need to be `await`ed. `'data-qa=login-input-email'` should be `'[data-qa="login-input-email"]'`.

I don't see anything at https://www.baseurl.com/login, so if the above fixes don't get you totally moving, please share it.

Comment: Also, don't forget to post the HTML markup [as text, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen, this is noted. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

One initial problem is that all of your `loginPage` methods need to be awaited:

```js
await loginPage.goto();
await loginPage.enterUsername(username);
await loginPage.enterPassword(password);
await loginPage.clickLoginBtn();
```

Selecting by attribute (`<a this-thing-is-an-attribute="some value">`) requires brackets:

```
page.locator('[data-qa="login-input-email"]');
```

Playwright offers a [convenience method for selecting by test id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75646919/6243352), along with a way to override the default of `data-testid`:

```js
selectors.setTestIdAttribute("data-qa");
this.loginButton = page.getByTestId("login-input-email");
```

Minimal example:

```js
import {expect, selectors, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.39.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<p data-qa="foo">hello</p></body></html>`;

test.beforeEach(() => selectors.setTestIdAttribute("data-qa"));

test("data-qa can be selected", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  await expect(page.getByTestId("foo")).toHaveText("hello");
});
```